# nft config to make a local NATed FTP server public available

Tags: ftp, nat, nftables

Everything will be on a isolated network, security is not an issue.
eth0 is connected to the "public" network. Address assigned by DHCP.
eth1 is connected to a "private network" server that provides ssh, telnet, "others" and ftp.
This server will have a fixed IP (192.168.1.2) in this example.

The gateway is running debian buster and Linux kernel 4.19.94

nft is used with NAT
This is my "gateway" nft configuration this far:

```
table ip my_nat {
    chain my_prerouting { type nat hook prerouting priority 0;
    tcp dport { 2222 } dnat to :22 # 2222 backdoor for ssh to the gateway
    tcp dport { 1-1023 } dnat to 192.168.1.2
  }
  chain my_postrouting {
    type nat hook postrouting priority 100;
    ip daddr 192.168.1.2  masquerade
  }
}
```

What do I need to add to make FTP work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

```
# nft add ct helper ip my_nat ftp-incoming '{ type "ftp" protocol tcp; }'
# nft add chain ip my_nat my_helpers '{ type filter hook prerouting priority 10; }'
# nft add rule ip my_nat my_helpers iif eth0 ip daddr 192.168.1.2 tcp dport 21 ct helper set ftp-incoming
# modprobe nf_nat_ftp
```

with more details below...

### Protocol helper modules for problematic protocols

FTP is an old protocol and is not very firewall-friendly: commands on the FTP command channel (21/TCP) negotiate an ephemeral port to use for the next transfer command. Because of this a stateful firewall has to snoop those commands and replies to temporarily pre-allow the adequate port about to be used.

On Linux this is provided by protocol-specific helper modules which are plugins to *conntrack*, the Netfilter subsystem tracking connections for NAT and stateful firewalling. With FTP, when a port negotiation (mostly PORT, EPRT, PASV or EPSV) for the next transfer has been seen on the FTP command port the helper adds a short-lived entry in a special *conntrack* table (the *conntrack expectation* table) which will wait the next related and expected data connection.

My answer uses the modern "secure" handling as described in [this blog about *iptables*](https://home.regit.org/netfilter-en/secure-use-of-helpers/) for generalities and in the [*nftables* wiki](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Setting_packet_connection_tracking_metainformation#helpers) and [`man nft`](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#CT) for the handling in *nftables* which differs from *iptables*.

### Secure use of helper and nftables rules

Linux kernel 4.7+ (so including 4.19) is using a secure approach by default: having the (here FTP) helper module loaded won't make it anymore snoop all packets having a TCP source or destination port 21, until specific *nftables* (or *iptables*) statements tell it in what (restricted) case it should snoop. This avoids unnecessary CPU usage and allows to change at any time the FTP port(s) to snoop just by changing a few rules (or sets).

The first part is to declare the flows that can trigger the snooping. It's handled differently in *nftables* than in *iptables*. Here it's declared using a `ct helper` stateful object, and filters to activate it must be done after *conntrack* (while *iptables* requires actions done before). [`man nft`](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#CT) tells:

> Unlike iptables, helper assignment needs to be performed after the
> conntrack lookup has completed, for example with the default 0 hook
> priority.

```
nft add ct helper ip my_nat ftp-incoming '{ type "ftp" protocol tcp; }'

nft add chain ip my_nat my_helpers '{ type filter hook prerouting priority 10; }'
nft add rule ip my_nat my_helpers iif eth0 ip daddr 192.168.1.2 tcp dport 21 ct helper set ftp-incoming
```

I chose the same table, but this could have been created in an other table, as long as the stateful object declaration and the rule referencing it are in the same table.

One can choose less restrictive rules of course. Replacing the last rule by this following rule would have the same effect as the legacy mode:

```
nft add rule ip my_nat my_helpers tcp dport 21 ct helper set ftp-incoming
```

For reference only, legacy mode, that shouldn't be used anymore, doesn't require the rules above but just this toggle (and the manual loading of the relevant kernel module):

```
sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_helper=1
```

### Ensuring `nf_nat_ftp` is loaded

The kernel module `nf_conntrack_ftp` is automatically loaded with the dependency created by `ct helper ... type "ftp"`. That's not the case for `nf_nat_ftp`, yet it is needed to also enable packet mangling in the command port when NAT is done on the data flow ports.

For example to have the module `nf_nat_ftp` pulled whenever `nf_conntrack_ftp` is loaded, the file `/etc/modprobe.d/local-nat-ftp.conf` could be added with this content:

```
install nf_conntrack_ftp /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install nf_conntrack_ftp; /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install nf_nat_ftp
```

or instead, simply add for example `/etc/modules-load.d/local-nat-ftp.conf` with:

```
nf_nat_ftp
```

Anyway right now this command should be done to ensure it's loaded:

```
modprobe nf_nat_ftp
```

---

### About firewalling

Here's an additional note for firewalling. There can also be firewalling rules with some restrictions instead of allowing any new flow tagged as *related* by *conntrack*.

For example, although the FTP helper module handles both passive and active modes, if for some reason one wants to allow only passive mode (with data connection from client to server) and not "active" ftp (data connection from server source port 20 to client) one could use for example these rules in the firewall part of the ruleset, instead of the usual `ct state established,related accept`:

```
ct state established accept
ct state related ct helper "ftp" iif eth0 oif eth1 tcp sport 1024-65535 accept
ct state related ct helper "ftp" drop
ct state related accept
```

Other kind of *related* flows not related to FTP are kept accepted (or could be further split separately)

---

### Example of handling by the helper

Here (in a simulated environment) are two *conntrack* lists of events measured on the *expectation* table and the *conntrack* table with OP's rules + the additional rules above with an Internet client 203.0.113.101 doing FTP in passive mode with the router's public IP address 192.0.2.2 and using a LIST command after having logged in:

```
# conntrack -E expect
    [NEW] 300 proto=6 src=203.0.113.101 dst=192.0.2.2 sport=0 dport=37157 mask-src=0.0.0.0 mask-dst=0.0.0.0 sport=0 dport=65535 master-src=203.0.113.101 master-dst=192.0.2.2 sport=50774 dport=21 class=0 helper=ftp
[DESTROY] 300 proto=6 src=203.0.113.101 dst=192.0.2.2 sport=0 dport=37157 mask-src=0.0.0.0 mask-dst=0.0.0.0 sport=0 dport=65535 master-src=203.0.113.101 master-dst=192.0.2.2 sport=50774 dport=21 class=0 helper=ftp
```

simultaneously:

```
# conntrack -E
    [NEW] tcp      6 120 SYN_SENT src=203.0.113.101 dst=192.0.2.2 sport=50774 dport=21 [UNREPLIED] src=192.168.1.2 dst=192.168.1.1 sport=21 dport=50774 helper=ftp
 [UPDATE] tcp      6 60 SYN_RECV src=203.0.113.101 dst=192.0.2.2 sport=50774 dport=21 src=192.168.1.2 dst=192.168.1.1 sport=21 dport=50774 helper=ftp
 [UPDATE] tcp      6 432000 ESTABLISHED src=203.0.113.101 dst=192.0.2.2 sport=50774 dport=21 src=192.168.1.2 dst=192.168.1.1 sport=21 dport=50774 [ASSURED] helper=ftp
    [NEW] tcp      6 120 SYN_SENT src=203.0.113.101 dst=192.0.2.2 sport=55835 dport=37157 [UNREPLIED] src=192.168.1.2 dst=192.168.1.1 sport=37157 dport=55835
 [UPDATE] tcp      6 60 SYN_RECV src=203.0.113.101 dst=192.0.2.2 sport=55835 dport=37157 src=192.168.1.2 dst=192.168.1.1 sport=37157 dport=55835
 [UPDATE] tcp      6 432000 ESTABLISHED src=203.0.113.101 dst=192.0.2.2 sport=55835 dport=37157 src=192.168.1.2 dst=192.168.1.1 sport=37157 dport=55835 [ASSURED]
 [UPDATE] tcp      6 120 FIN_WAIT src=203.0.113.101 dst=192.0.2.2 sport=55835 dport=37157 src=192.168.1.2 dst=192.168.1.1 sport=37157 dport=55835 [ASSURED]
 [UPDATE] tcp      6 30 LAST_ACK src=203.0.113.101 dst=192.0.2.2 sport=55835 dport=37157 src=192.168.1.2 dst=192.168.1.1 sport=37157 dport=55835 [ASSURED]
 [UPDATE] tcp      6 120 TIME_WAIT src=203.0.113.101 dst=192.0.2.2 sport=55835 dport=37157 src=192.168.1.2 dst=192.168.1.1 sport=37157 dport=55835 [ASSURED]
```

The expectation's start `proto=6 src=203.0.113.101 dst=192.0.2.2 sport=0 dport=37157` tells that the next TCP connection from 203.0.113.101:* to 192.0.2.2:37157 will be associated (state *related*) with the FTP connection. Not visible directly, but since the NAT FTP helper module is also loaded, the actual data sent by the server in response to the PASV/EPSV command was intercepted and translated so the client connects to 192.0.2.2 instead of 192.168.1.2 which would have of course failed on the client.

Despite the second flow (second *NEW* line) having no explicit rule in *my_prerouting*, it was succesfully DNATed to the server behind the router.

---

### Notes

- if the FTP control port is encrypted (`AUTH TLS` ...), then the helper module can't snoop the negotiated port anymore and this can't work. One have to resort to configuring a reserved range of ports both on the FTP server configuration and the firewall/NAT router, and configure the server so it sends the correct (public) IP address when negotiating instead of its own. And active FTP mode can't be used if the server has no route to Internet (as appears to be the case here).
- nitpicking: the prerouting priority of 10 ensures that even for kernels < 4.18, NAT already happened for new flows (OP chose hook prerouting priority 0 instead of the usual -100 as this rarely matters in nftables), so the use of `daddr 192.168.1.2` is possible. If the priority was 0 (or lower than 0), it's perhaps possible (not verified) the rule would see the first packet still unNATed with a public IP destination address, but would catch the following packets of the same flow, since they are handled directly by *conntrack* at priority -200. Better stay safe and use 10. Actually this is not relevant since kernel 4.18 (see [commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?id=9971a514ed2697e542f3984a6162eac54bb1da98) reference in [this](http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/netfilter-devel/patch/20200814130743.29024-1-fw@strlen.de/) pending patch) where NAT priority is only relevant for comparing between multiple nat chains (and allows mixing NAT in iptables legacy along nftables).

Comment: that's a well written and well detailed explanation. kudos

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error I've come up with the following nftables.conf
This works as intended and supports NAT in both directions as well as exporting all but one port on my server to the "public" network. Port 2222 is still used as a "backdoor" to the gateway, to be used if i ever need to access it again :-)

```
table ip my_nat {
        ct helper ftp-incoming {
                type "ftp" protocol tcp
                l3proto ip
        }

        chain my_prerouting {
                type nat hook prerouting priority 0; policy accept;
                iifname "eth0" tcp dport { 2222 } dnat to :ssh
                iifname "eth0" tcp dport { 1-2221, 2223-65535 } dnat to 192.168.0.2
        }

        chain my_postrouting {
                type nat hook postrouting priority 100; policy accept;
                ip daddr 192.168.0.2 masquerade
                oifname "eth0" masquerade
        }

        chain my_helpers {
                type filter hook prerouting priority 10; policy accept;
                iif "eth0" ip daddr 192.168.0.2 tcp dport ftp ct helper set "ftp-incoming"
        }

}
```